# Xcode 12 errors with FBSDK

Tags: ios, fbsdk, xcode12

I have many errors coming from FBSDK when running Xcode 12 that I would not get any on Xcode 11.

> Duplicate interface definition for class 'FBSDKGraphRequestConnection'
> Property has a previous declaration No type or protocol named
> 'FBSDKCopying' Reference to 'FBSDKCopying' is ambiguous Duplicate
> interface definition for class 'FBSDKAccessToken'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had FBSDK 7.1.1 then I updated to FBSDK 8.0 and it solved the issue.